# How to match different substring using perl regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl

Take below strings for example

```
abc12, abc13, abc23, abc288, abd12
```

What regular string should be used if I only want to match abc12 and abc13.

I thought it should be `abc[(12)|(13)]`, so `12` and `13` will be grouped together and match either of them, but it turns out, this string will match all strings above.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do, but `$str =~ /^abc1(?:2|3)$/` will match only  `abc12` and `abc13`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current regex is not doing what you think it is:

```
abc[(12)|(13)]
```

This says to match `abc` followed by any one of the following characters:

```
1, 2, 3, (, ), or |
```

The characters inside the bracket are part of a *character class*, or group of characters which can be matched.  For your use case, you probably want something like this:

```
abc1[23]
```

This matches `abc1` followed by only a `2` or a `3`.

If you wanted to match `abc12` or `abc23` you could use this:

```
abc(?:12|23)
```

Here we can't really use a character class, but we can use an *alternation* instead.  The quantity in parentheses will match either `12` or `23`.  If you are wondering what `?:` does, it simply tells the Perl regex engine *not* to capture what is inside parentheses, which is what it would be doing by default.

Comment: abc1[23] work for this example. But what if I want to match abc12 and abc23, whatever I just mean to match several substrings inside a regular expresssion. Is it possible? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I want, I know the expression ?:, but never thought it could do this! Thanks a lot.